# Passing Arrays using POINTERS in CBLLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I have a situation in my project, we have to retrieve values in array using pointer. I was able to get the pointer value in my Called program with the array being in working-storage section,

in my calling program, i am able to retrieve the pointer value and have defined the array in LINKAGE section to overcome the limitations of compiler and have not used that array in procedure division, however the program I am facing is that I am not able to get all the elements in the array. Any clue how to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you want help with code, post it... along with a more precise definition of the problem than "I am not able to get all the elements in the array". Which elements couldn't you get? Why not? Did you get an error? Were the other elements' values wrong?

Comment: Interesting question with a likely solution, if the question is changed to include code of table defintion in calller and callee, together with passing the pointer parts and ideally with some sample output....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array in the `LINKAGE SECTION` of the calling program has the same definition as the array in the `WORKING-STORAGE SECTION` of the called program, (it's not clear without the code) then `COBOL 85` provided the means to do so without pointers. Just use the `EXTERNAL` clause. For example,

```
   program-id. prog-1.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       call "prog-2"
       call "prog-3"
       stop run
       .
   end program prog-1.

   program-id. prog-2.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 xdata01 external pic x(1024).
   1 array redefines xdata01.
    2 array-item pic x(16) occurs 64.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       move all "abcd" to array
       exit program
       .
   end program prog-2.

   program-id. prog-3.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 x binary pic 9(4).
   1 xdata01 external pic x(1024).
   1 array redefines xdata01.
    2 array-item pic x(16) occurs 64.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       perform varying x from 1 by 1
       until x > 64
           display array-item (x)
       end-perform
       exit program
       .
   end program prog-3.

abcdabcdabcdabcd
abcdabcdabcdabcd
abcdabcdabcdabcd
abcdabcdabcdabcd
abcdabcdabcdabcd
(64 lines total)
```

In this example, `prog-2` fills the array and `prog-3` uses the array. The `data-name`, `xdata01` (use whatever name your system permits), is the name used by the system to make the same uninitialized memory available to both programs.

In terms of equivalence, `ADDRESS OF xdata01` is a pointer to `array` in the called program, thus there is no need to pass a pointer or even use one; and the definition of `array` in the calling program matches the definition in the called program, thus there is no need to place the definition of `array` in the `LINKAGE SECTION` or use a pointer to access the data.